# Using sw-toolbox with gulp

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, sw-precache, sw-toolbox

I read many tutorials about sw-toolbox and sw-precache.
The doubt i am having is :

When reading about sw-precache, i found out most tutorials are using `gulp + sw-precache`.

Whereas in `sw-toolbox` case, i saw the example and syntaxes given only for writing code in `service-worker.js` directly (no gulpfile code).

I am using gulp to automatically generate `service-worker` file .

So my main concern is to write code for `sw-toolbox` in gulp file directly so that i need not write `sw-toolbox` code after generating `sw-precache` with `gulp`

Please comment for doubts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You no need to write separate code manually for `sw-toolbox`. You can configure it using `runtimeCaching` option in `sw-precache`. As soon as you configured this option, `sw-precache` will insert `sw-toolbox` library in serviceWorker and adds different handlers to it. You can find more details from this [link](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#runtimecaching-arrayobject).

Comment: so Is runtimeCaching is simlar to sw-toolbox's router.get()?
Does it provide all the features like maxage,networktimeoutseconds etc

Answer (score -2):

When using sw-precache it generates the service worker and you can't edit that file.

When using sw-precache I'd ignore sw-toolbox and just focus on how to configure sw-precache to cache static files and cache runtime files (I.e. cache images or pages as they are requested)

Comment: If i want to use sw-toolbox and precache both

Comment: You can't so it easily. It's not the way SW-precache was designed to be used.

Comment: see the above answer..And hell yeah, we can obviously edit it after it ahs been generated by the gulp file.

Comment: The entire point of sw-precache is lost if you edit the service worker after it's been generated.

The file revisions are set for that instance of files and designed that when you change the files it forces an update, if you manually just change the service worker file and don't update with sw-precache you will end up with some funky problems with users further down the line.

Comment: Okay. It got your point but my doubt is after generating my service worker file with gulp, If I delete my all files(gulp.js,node_modules folder) and leave only service-worker and ofcourse  manifest.json; Then also it works normally. And moreover, if i change service worker file manually, it also works as expected(like service worker getting updated in next refresh ).

Comment: The caching rules for the service worker generated by precache is designed such that no changes are made to the precached assets unless the filerevisions are updated, which is intended to be done by the gulp build process.

So while it might appear "to work and update" I question if you are actually getting fresh content, if your users will get fresh content and how long before you hit a real issue :(

Comment: See changing  anything in the service worker, makes an update to the service worker file. And it gives the user fresh content as and when handled by the user in the activate event.

Comment: The fetch even in the sw-precache file ONLY looks in the cache. The service worker file will update, but if the file revisions aren't updated, the install step will not attempt to update the cached files (A feature of sw-precache), meaning that changes to assets aren't cached, meaning the response from the fetch event is the old version of a file from the cache NOT the network.